# How do I copy files from within a Frida-gadget cli?

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, frida

In an un-rooted android environment the `adb shell` is limited to and confined to permissions granted to it. Therefore, when debugging an Frida-gadget app, sometimes it's the need to copy files from directories accessible only to the content of the application. In this scenario it was hard to find a solution on how to do it.

How do I copy a file from source to dest?

Comment: [Objection](https://github.com/sensepost/objection) has AFAIR functionality included that allows file listing and manipulation in an interactive way.

Comment: @Robert You are correct; `com.android.app on (PHONE: 12) [usb] # android shell_exec cp --help`

Answer (score 2):

It's possible using `java.io.File` class:

```
function copyfile(source, destination) {
    const File = Java.use('java.io.File');
    const FileInputStream = Java.use('java.io.FileInputStream');
    const FileOutputStream = Java.use('java.io.FileOutputStream');
    const BufferedInputStream = Java.use('java.io.BufferedInputStream');
    const BufferedOutputStream = Java.use('java.io.BufferedOutputStream');
    var sourceFile = File.$new.overload('java.lang.String').call(File, source);
    if (sourceFile.exists() && sourceFile.canRead()) {
        var destinationFile = File.$new.overload('java.lang.String').call(File, destination);
        destinationFile.createNewFile();
        var fileInputStream = FileInputStream.$new.overload('java.io.File').call(FileInputStream, sourceFile);
        var fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream.$new.overload('java.io.File').call(FileOutputStream, destinationFile);
        var bufferedInputStream = BufferedInputStream.$new.overload('java.io.InputStream').call(BufferedInputStream, fileInputStream);
        var bufferedOutputStream = BufferedOutputStream.$new.overload('java.io.OutputStream').call(BufferedOutputStream, fileOutputStream);
        var data = 0;
        while ((data = bufferedInputStream.read()) != -1) {
            bufferedOutputStream.write(data);
        }
        console.log('finished copying to : ' + destination);
        bufferedInputStream.close();
        fileInputStream.close();
        bufferedOutputStream.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    }
    else {
        console.log('Error : File cannot read.')
    }
}
```

Comment: On an Andrid 8+ device, I would prefer [File.copy(..)](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/nio/file/Files?hl=en#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption)) instead of copying a file byte by byte which will take some time for larger files.